# Sonarqube and Jenkins install on windows 64 bit - jre was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

We have installed Jave JRE 8 on our Jenkins build server and successfully have installed Sonarqube, and it runs fine from our local IP:9000.  Jenkins project appears to be set up properly as well and the SonarQube plugin is installed.

When setting up an MS Build project with SonarQube, it errors at the end of the process.  The Sonarqube begin analysis step works fine, the build itself is working fine, but when we add in the SonarQube end analysis, it errors as such:

```
10:17:19 \Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\Sonar_Scanner_for_MSBuild\sonar-scanner-3.0.1.733\bin..\jre was unexpected at this time. 
10:17:19 The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
```

We have tried to adjust both JAVA_HOME and the PATH variable accordingly, but are at a loss as to how to fix.

Comment: Actually, it looks more like the shell interpreter has a problem with parsing the file, as if there is a syntax error on line 23 in `sonar-scanner-3.0.1.733\bin\sonar-scanner.bat`. A bit more context from the error log might help. It would be also good for debugging to execute this script from the shell of Jenkins

Comment: I created a ticket to track this problem: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SQSCANNER-41

Comment: Can you please try this workaround by editing `sonar-scanner.bat` like in this comment: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli/pull/31#issuecomment-300739312

Comment: What is the Jenkins work directory? I find the path really strange: `\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation...` Why is the drive letter missing?

Comment: The fix has been released in [3.0.3](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-a-scanner.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this issue on our Jenkins server when switching from the runner to the scanner for MSBuild. I fixed it by having the jenkins plugin install the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.3.0.527 instead of the lastest version 2.3.1.554.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Completely right, it was a bug in the newest version, saved me a ton of aggravation we have been going through!  Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration.  Within the Sonarqube for MSBuild, select the 2nd newest version and save.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.0 release included a small change to `sonar-scanner.bat` that didn't handle correctly the case when the installation path of the scanner included parentheses. Users who installed the scanner under for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\some\path` would get the error message as in the question. The error message itself is pretty non-sense, because the way variables are interpreted in DOS, the parentheses in the value of `%SONAR_SCANNER_HOME%` make the syntax invalid, so the DOS interpreter gets completely confused.

The problem occurred here in the script:

```
set use_embedded_jre=${use_embedded_jre}
if "%use_embedded_jre%" == "true" (
  set JAVA_HOME=%SONAR_SCANNER_HOME%\jre
)
```

And the fix was to change like this:

```
set use_embedded_jre=${use_embedded_jre}
if "%use_embedded_jre%" == "true" (
  set "JAVA_HOME=%SONAR_SCANNER_HOME%\jre"
)
```

It's important to have the double-quotes around the entire variable assignment,
not just around the right-hand side of the `=` operator.
Otherwise if `%SONAR_SCANNER_HOME%` already contained double-quotes due to embedded spaces, the script wouldn't work.

This has been fixed in 3.0.3, and available for [download](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-a-scanner.html).